# RubyMine 2016.2.1, Strip trailing spaces on Save not work

Tags: rubymine

The RubyMine version 2016.2.1 not work `Strip trailing spaces on Save`. I think this worked with pre version.

My Preferences

[image]

My Code

[image]

the code have unnecessary only white lines.

How to remove the only white lines? is this RubyMine bug?

Comment: You can ask ur question on their official site, https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us , they are very responsive and helpful.

Comment: oh. I try https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207665709-The-RubyMine-version-2016-2-1-not-work-Strip-trailing-spaces-on-Save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked [The RubyMine version 2016.2.1 not work Strip trailing spaces on Save – JetBrains Support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207665709-The-RubyMine-version-2016-2-1-not-work-Strip-trailing-spaces-on-Save?page=1#community_comment_203688410).

> Settings > Editor > Code Style > Ruby > Keep indents on empty lines was checked! I unchecked, tested the editor and it seems just fine :-)

Uncheck `Ruby > Keep indents on empty lines`, then work.